# want to retrieve values from a give range of dates from database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to fetch values in the following manner:

I want to fetch the total value for current weeks count and my code is here:

```
SimpleDateFormat weekDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
Date weekFirstDate = c.getTime();
String strWeekFirstDay = weekDateFormat.format(weekFirstDate);
Cursor weekCursor = database.rawQuery("select sum(cat_attribute_unit) from counter where cat_id ="+cat_id+" AND counter_entry_date BETWEEN '"+strWeekFirstDay+"' AND '"+todays_date+"';", null);
int weekCounter = 0;
if(weekCursor.moveToFirst())
    weekCounter = weekCursor.getInt(0);
else
    weekCounter = 0;
weekCursor.close();
```

And this is the code for fetching current month's total count:

```
SimpleDateFormat monthDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    Date monthFirstDate = c2.getTime();
    String strMonthFirstDay = monthDateFormat.format(monthFirstDate);

    Cursor monthCursor = database.rawQuery("select sum(cat_attribute_unit) from counter where cat_id ="+cat_id+" AND counter_entry_date BETWEEN '"+strMonthFirstDay+"' AND '"+todays_date+"';", null);
    int monthCounter = 0;
    if(monthCursor.moveToFirst())
        monthCounter = monthCursor.getInt(0);
    else
        monthCounter = 0;
    monthCursor.close()
```

is this correct ?? because its not working properly, means i get wrong values. Also i want to make my week start from Monday. Would anyone pls correct my code or suggest some new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all your dates in this format and try again..

`MM-dd-yyyy`

```
Cursor monthCursor = database.rawQuery("select sum(cat_attribute_unit) from counter where cat_id ="+cat_id+" AND counter_entry_date BETWEEN '"+strMonthFirstDay+"' AND '"+todays_date+"';", null);
```

Comment: it also worked with the format "yyyy/MM/dd". Previously the format which i kept was "dd/MM/yyyy". Anyway, thanks for helping, friend....